# Android: Creating a parent layout and extending it to maintain an identical look and feel across all activities of the application

Tags: android, user-interface, inheritance, layout

I am writing an app in which I have mutiple screens which I want to adhere to a certain theme.
For example: all screens should have the same background, all screens should have a bar on the top with the same set of actions (not necessarily dependent on the activity currently being show) and all screens should share the same fonts.
Is there a way in android to create a parent layout which all other layouts extend and therefore if I need to change some elements (say the background color) I won't have to do it on each individual screen but rather only in the parent screen.
I guess what I'm asking is, is there a sort of layout inheritance in android?

Thanks,
e.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no layout inheritance but you can create this bar layout in a separate file and use [include](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html) to include it in the layouts that you want to have the bar.

Some of the other stuff could also be done with [styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html). Create a style for different elements and then add the style to the element in the layouts.

To do inheritance you can create a layout that you can include in other layouts. Then in a BaseActivity you can modify views, add event listeners, etc for the included layout. Just make sure in your `onCreate` to call `setContentView()` before you call `super.onCreate().`

Comment: that sucks...
What about creating an activity that all the other activities extend?
that way we can get the layout and maybe somehow include a child viewgroup (pretty similar to what android does when they launch an app and put it in a frame layout)
do you think that's possible?

Comment: I'm gonna give it a try, I'm not sure it will answer everything I need but I'll see what can be achieved anyway.
Thanks!

Comment: The 'Include' link seems to be broken. Think it should be http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html

Comment: Can you set the font of a TextView in an included XML from a parent BaseActivity class? I'm trying to do it but the font does not change unless I call `setTypeface` from an Activity the extends the BaseActivity.

Comment: I think the verbosity benefits to static layouts far out weight the maintenance overhead of their inherent duplicate code, and are significantly easier to maintain than obfuscated code that dynamically constructs views. I create layouts for the child most view that is to be inflated, which derives from a base class that defines common functionality (not appearance).

Comment: ... Also, modifying an isolated, child-level class/view/layout has minimal impact and allows for quick compilation and testing without having to first implement the adjustment application-wide. The change can then be integrated one view at a time, which I find useful since exceptions do arise along the way. Doing it "all in one shot" is infeasible, wasteful, and infuriating.